# Make JWindow of swing to appear full screen and components inside it also should adjust accordingly

Tags: java, swing, fullscreen

I have a panel which comes on top of another panel which is made using JWindow. I want to set this top panel go fullscreen when a button is clicked. I searched in for long time but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: *"..and components inside it also should adjust accordingly"* [Layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution takes the current screen dimensions and sets the frame size to it. The setSize() call also exists for JWindow.

```
frame = new JFrame("Test");  
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  
int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());  
int ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());  
frame.setSize(xSize,ySize);
```

source: http://www.coderanch.com/t/341780/GUI/java/set-Jframe-full-screen

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is downvoted. It works.